# Find unique values for all the columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can i get the unique values of all the column in a dataframe ?
I am trying to do something like below as of now.

```
for col in train_features_df.columns:
    print(train_features_df.col.unique())
```

But this gives me the error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'`

For e.g for below dataframe i want to the below output

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3],
               'B':[4,5,6],
               'C':[7,7,7]})
```

I want a output of 1,3 for A and 4,5,6 for B and 7 for C .

Comment: do you expect a dictionary or a dataframe: `{col: df[col].unique() for col in df.columns}` ?

Comment: @anky : I am expecting dictionary , what is rational behind this working in single line but not in multiple lines ?

Comment: Simply put, a dataframe expects equal length arrays but when you apply the function on the dataframe, the output is arrays of unequal length. In this case, it allows you to create a dictionary by iterating each column however it wouldn't allow you to create a dataframe from the same using `pd.DataFrame(d)` unless you transpose it `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index').T`, transposing works because the function can use each row as an array when applied on `axis=1`, pandas is index aligned

Comment: @anky: Thanks but if reason is unequal length arrays does that mean if number of unique items each column are same would that be allowed :) I got the essence of what you are conveying thanks for that.

Comment: Yes it wil allow check `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3],'B':[4,4,6],'C':[7,7,8]})` and then `df.apply(np.unique)` it would return 2 unique rows for each column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply `unique` on each series by transposing like,

```
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  1  5  7
2  3  6  7
>>> df.T.apply(lambda x: x.unique(), axis=1)
A       [1, 3]
B    [4, 5, 6]
C          [7]
dtype: object
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `for loop` with `drop_duplicates()` to get your desired result, No need to use any complex function.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3],'B':[4,5,6],'C':[7,7,7]})

for i in df.columns:
    print(f'{i} : {list(df[i].drop_duplicates())}')
```

Output will be as below:

```
A : [1, 3]
B : [4, 5, 6]
C : [7]
```